# MySQL query syntax error in CREATE TABLE near UNIQUE KEY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have executed this query in MySQL but it is showing `a syntax error near Unique key statement`. Can anybody help me to clear the error?

```
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
      `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `providerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `requestId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `status` binary(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),

       UNIQUE KEY `Index_3` (`providerId`,`requestId`),
       KEY `Index_2` (`providerId`,`requestId`,`status`))
       ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 
       COMMENT='providerId is the Id of the users who wish to be friend with' AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

The error message is given below:

**ERROR 1064(42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Id'),UNIQUE KEY Index_2(providerId,requestId),KEY Index_3 (providerId,requ' at line 1**

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: Redundant comma here: `status binary(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (Id),`

Comment: The statement you posted works for me (See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56e8d/1) Which SQL client do you use to run this? And what is your MySQL version?

Comment: version 5.6.13 enterprise commercial advanced

Comment: yeah I have seen that it works but why it is not working in my system? Is there any problem with the version?

Comment: The quote marks reported in the error message don't match the quote marks reported in the SQL statement.  Which set got changed?

Answer (score 2):

there is unnecessary `,` at the end

```
`status` binary(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
```

Comment: I have removed that comma but still showing error..is there any problem in using "index"?

Comment: The comma *is* necessary because there are more constraints coming after that.

Comment: ok so If I put the comma back it is showing the same error message..is it because of any other problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put key words `PRIMARY KEY ('Id')` in first column, after `... AUTO_INCREMENT`, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
       `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `providerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `requestId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `status` binary(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

       UNIQUE KEY `Index_3` (`providerId`,`requestId`),
       KEY `Index_2` (`providerId`,`requestId`,`status`))
       ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 
       COMMENT='providerId is the Id of the users who wish to be friend with' AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

Comment: well the error was clear now thanks to all of you guys for the help..good day :)

Comment: missed '' last on comment !! oops

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO Carttable  (id unique,date,title,supplier,item_price,item_qty,author,author_image,image,image2,image3,categories,categories_id,main_category_id,tags,post_data,views,status,item_status,discount,offer_price,qty_1,price_1,offer_price_1,qty_2,price_2,offer_price_2,qty_3,price_3,offer_price_3,mcid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: Add an explanation how this helps solve the original error